# how to add condition to exclude user name from php string

Tags: php, wordpress

The following is working to exclude the name of the author from a particular category of posts in Wordpress. I want to also exclude certain authors (users) from having their name appear on posts. How do I extend this code to do that?

```
<?php if ( !in_category('10') ) { ?>
by <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried this below and received an unexpected else error:

```
<?php if ( !in_category('10') )
else (!user_id('7') )
 { ?>
by <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your if/else statement has incorrect syntax. PHP is seeing the else block as being inside the if statement, and not complimentary to. You need to add a line, or some empty brackets, after your first if statement (typically, having a logic statement followed by empty brackets means you should rethink the logic, though).

Comment: sorry, what do you mean regarding the logic of a statement with empty brackets?

Comment: hey means that you did `if (condition) else (condition) {statement}` when it should have been `if (condition) { statement } else (condition) { statement }` but that's not what you really wanted anyways

Comment: @Chris: I meant what Crayon described. I made it as a comment because it doesn't answer your question, but it was incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to exclude if both category 10 AND user 7:

```
<?php if ( !in_category('10') && !user_id('7') ) { ?>
by <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to exclude if either category 10 OR user 7:

```
<?php if ( !in_category('10') || !user_id('7') ) { ?>
by <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

**edit**: based on comments, looks like `user_id()` isn't the function you actually need. Looks like you may want this instead:

```
<?php if (!in_category('10') || get_the_author_meta('ID')=='7' ) { ?>
by <?php the_author(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The first works but the second gets me "Fatal error: Call to undefined function post_author"

is user_id the wrong term to use here?

Comment: @Chris I don't know, probably. I don't know wordpress's functions; I simply showed you correct syntax for calling the function I assumed you already worked out

Comment: I do want to get the second to work as I need to exclude either the specific category or the specific user.

Comment: @Chris if i had to *guess* i'd think it was probably something more like `author_id()` or `the_author_id()` or maybe even a parameter to `the_author()` e.g. `the_author('id')` but I'm just guessing here. You should read whatever documentation Wordpress provides to see how they expose it

Comment: Thank you for your help with the syntax, the problem is definitely the user_id function.

Comment: @Chris also fyi the first probably works because of short circuiting. If the first part of the condition `!in_category('10')` is false then php already knows the entire condition is false so it doesn't bother to evaluate the 2nd part of the condition. IOW it should throw the same fatal error if the category *is* 10 and php has a chance to evaluate the 2nd part of the condition. IOW `if (s1 && s2)` since both `s1` and `s2` must be true in order for the condition to be true, if `s1` is false, php doesn't have to evaluate `s2` because the condition has already been determined.

Comment: OK, the correct term is the_author_id(). However when I try to use that with either $$ or ||, instead of working, it adds a "2" before "by [author]". Which is strange.

Comment: @Chris okay, so it's *sounds* like `the_author_id()` might be on the right track but not what you really need. I notice that for `the_author()` you aren't actually echoing it out, so the function must be outputting the value instead of just returning it, and `the_author_id()` is probably doing the same thing.  So there is probably another function for just returning (instead of outputting) the author id, or else maybe an optional parameter to pass to `the_author_id()` to make it return the value instead of output it

Comment: @Chris This looks promising.. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-a-post-authors-id-in-single-post-view

Comment: @Chris or this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta  i would try `if ( !in_category('10') || get_the_author_meta('ID')=='7' ) { ... }`

Comment: Somehow this works:

    <?php if ( !in_category('10') && get_the_author_meta('ID')=='2,4,5' ) { ?>
    by <?php the_author(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Use one if-statements and the && (AND) operator:

```
<?php if ( !in_category('10') && !user_id('7') ) { ?>
    by <?php the_author(); 
} ?>
```